# How can I call array patient name to compare by namebase?

Tags: java, queue

Can not find getName();

You have to implement a waiting room management system in an emergency ward of a hospital.  Your program will assign an Id number to a patient in a first come first serve basis. The lower the id, the sooner the service will be provided to the patient.

ShowAllPatient():This method shows all ids of the waiting patients in SORTED order. (Hint: use the sorting methods learnt in class using the appropriate data-structure for each task) [Sorted according to their names]

```
**/ import java.util.Scanner;
    //import static java.lang.System.*;
    public class Tester {
        public static void main(String [] args){
            String input;
            WatingRoomManagment b= new WatingRoomManagment();
            System.out.println("1 Array Based \n2 Linkedlist Based");
            String type=new Scanner(System.in).next();
            if(type.equals("1")){
                b.arrayQueue();
            }
            else if(type.equals("2")){
                b.ListQueue();
            }
                do
            {
                System.out.println("Hospital Wating Room Managment Service");  
                System.out.println("1. Add a new Patient");
                System.out.println("2. Serve a patient");
                System.out.println("3. Can Doctor go Home?");
                System.out.println("4. Cancel All appointment");
                System.out.println("5. Display all Patient Information");
                System.out.println("6. Quit");

                System.out.println("Please enter either 1 to 6: "); 
                input =(new Scanner(System.in).next());

                if (input.equals("1")){
                    System.out.println("Name: ");
                    String nam=new Scanner(System.in).next();
                    System.out.println("Age: ");
                    String age=new Scanner(System.in).next();
                    System.out.println("blood: ");
                    String blood=new Scanner(System.in).next();
                    paitent a = new paitent(nam,age,blood);
                    b.RegisterPatient(a);
                }
                else if (input.equals("2")){
                    b.serveapatient();
                }
                else if(input.equals("3")){
                    b.CanDoctorgoHome();
                }
                else if(input.equals("4")){
                    b.cancelAll();
                }
                else if (input.equals("5")){
                    b.showAllpatient();
                }
            }while(!input.equals("6"));
        }
    }
    class paitent {
        String name;
        int id;
        String age;
        String blood;
        paitent(String name,String age,String blood){
            this.name=name;
            this.age=age;
            this.blood=blood;
            this.id=idGen();
        }
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
        public String toString(){
            String s= id+" "+name+" age "+age+" Blood "+blood;
            return s;
        }


        public int idGen() {

            int id = this.name.hashCode() + this.blood.hashCode();
            int length = String.valueOf(id).length();
            int Max_Length = 5;
            if(String.valueOf(id).length()>Max_Length) 
            {
                id = (int) (id /Math.pow(10.0,length - Max_Length ));
            }
            return  id;
        }
    }
    class WatingRoomManagment {
        static Queue q1;
        void arrayQueue(){
            q1= new ArrayQueue();
        }
        void ListQueue(){
            q1= new ListQueue();
        }
        void RegisterPatient(paitent k){
            try{
                q1.enqueue(k);
            }
            catch(QueueOverflowException e){
                System.err.println("Queue Full! Cannot Enqueue\n"+e);
            }
        }
        void serveapatient(){

            try{
                q1.dequeue();
            }
            catch(QueueUnderflowException e){
                System.err.println("Queue Empty\n"+e);
            }
        }
        void showAllpatient(){
            Object [] names=q1.toArray();
            Object temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
                for (int j = i + 1; j < names.length-1; j++){
                    if(names[i].getName().compareTo(names[j].getName())>0){
                        temp = names[i];
                        names[i] = names[j];
                        names[j] = temp;
                   }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(q1.toString());
        }
        void CanDoctorgoHome(){
            if(q1.isEmpty())
                System.out.println("Yes. He can go now");
            else
                System.out.println("No.");
        }
        void cancelAll(){
            q1.cancel();
        }
    }
    class ArrayQueue implements Queue {
        int size=0;
        int rear=-1;
        int front=-1;

        Object[] a = new Object[10];

        public void enqueue(paitent k)throws QueueOverflowException{
            if(size==a.length){
                throw new QueueOverflowException();
            }
            if(size==0){
                a[0]=k;
                a[(rear+1)%a.length]=k;
                rear=(rear+1)%a.length;
                front=(front+1)%a.length;
                size++;
            }
            else{      
                a[(rear+1)%a.length]=k;
                rear=(rear+1)%a.length;
                size++;
            }
        }
        public void dequeue() throws QueueUnderflowException{
            if(size==0)
                throw new QueueUnderflowException();
            a[front%a.length]=null;
            front=(front+1)%a.length;
            size--;
        }
        public boolean isEmpty(){
            if(size==0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        public Object[] toArray(){
            Object[] temp = new Object[size];
            int start=front;
            for(int i=0; i<temp.length ; i++){
                temp[i]=a[start];
                start=(start+1)%a.length;
            }
            return temp;
        }
        public String toString(){
            String p="";
            if(size==0){
                p=p+"No is here";
            }
            else{
                int st=front;
                for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
                    p=p+" "+a[st]+"\n";
                    st=(st+1)%a.length;
                } 
            }
            return p;
        }
        public void cancel(){
            int st=front;
            for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
                a[st]=null;
                st=(st+1)%a.length;
            }
            size=0;
        }
        public int size(){
            return size;
        }
    }
    class ListQueue implements Queue{
        int size;
        Node front;
        Node rear;


        public ListQueue(){
            size = 0;
            front = null;
            rear = null;
        }
        public void enqueue(paitent o) throws QueueOverflowException{
            Node temp=new Node(o,null);
            if(size==0){
                front=temp;
                rear=front;
                size++;
            }
            else if(size>0){
                rear.next=temp;
                rear=temp;
                size++;
            }
        }
         public void dequeue() throws QueueUnderflowException {
            if(size==0){
                throw new QueueUnderflowException();
            }
            Node mn = front;
            if(size==1){
                rear=null;
                front=null;
                size--;
            }
            if(size>0){
                front = front.next;
                size--;
            }
            mn.val= null;
            mn.next= null;
        }
         public boolean isEmpty(){
            if(size==0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
         public String toString(){
            if(size==0)
                return "Empty Queue";
            else{
                String s = "[ ";
                for(Node n = front; n!=null; n=n.next){
                    s = s + n.val+ " ";
                }
                return s + "]";
            }
        }
         public Object[] toArray() {
            Object a [] = new Object [size];
            int i =0;
            for(Node n = front; n!=null; n=n.next){
                a[i] = n.val;i++;
            }
            return a; 
        }
         public void cancel(){
             front=null;
             rear=null;
             size=0;
         }
         public int size(){
             return size;
         }
    }
    class Node{
        paitent val;
        Node next;

        public Node(paitent v, Node n){
            val = v;
            next = n;
        }
    }
    interface Queue { 
        public int size(); 
        public boolean isEmpty(); 
        public void enqueue(paitent k) throws QueueOverflowException; 
        public void dequeue() throws QueueUnderflowException;
        public String toString();
        public Object[] toArray();
        public void cancel();
    }
    class QueueOverflowException extends Exception{

    }
    class QueueUnderflowException extends Exception{
    }**/
```

Comment: Hi and welcome!  Please simplify your code example so that it is specific to the problem you are trying to solve, and more importantly, show us what you have tried and the errors you receive.  For reference, please give this a read as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your line calling "getName" with this line

```
if(((patient)names[i]).getName().compareTo(((patient)names[j]).getName())>0)
```

Because your array "names", is defined as an array of Objects and not as an array of specific types, you will probably need to cast its elements to "patient"s before the compiler is able to see what methods are available.

Comment: I am facing same problem. I want to compare patient class name variable which is contain in queue array.